# Adjusting Container View's Height to Match Embedded UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I'm implementing multiple uitableview in single view controller. now I want my container view same height as my embedded UITableView. How can i achieve it?[image]

Comment: UITableViews are inherited from scrollView so they can scroll if the content size is greater than the window provided to them, so usually u'll not increase the size of the container based on the embedded view especially if it has scrollView, is your tableView's scroll disabled? If yes, are their size fixed (which I believe will lead to more troubles) if yes then you can add height constraint to your container view and provide a identifier to your embed segue, implement prepare for segue and in prepareforSegue based on destinationVC type change the constraint constant value

Comment: I just want to show the first 3 products in the table without scrolling. and I need to set the height the content of the tableview to it's height. but im stuck on containers view height to embedded table.

Comment: If your cell height is fixed, I have already answered in my first comment, implement prepareForSegue, add a identifier to embed segue of yours in storyboard, catch the destination VC, if the destination VC is of type of your interest change the container's height constraint constant to 3 * height of cell and call layoutIfNeeded on containerView thats all you need. If embedded view controllers are loaded statically and no dynamic changes happening then u don't even have to implement prepareForSegue rather directly update constraint in awakeFromNib or set it directly in your storyboard

Comment: I'll try it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched, I got pointed in the right direction - specifically, that this is not possible the way I thought it was.

There is no way to have constraints between the views of a parent view controller and a child view controller - neither in IB, nor in code

As far as I can see, there are two ways to solve this:

Don't use a second UIViewController. Make the root view of your child view controller an actual subview of yourself, and just have a single UIViewController.

Do not use auto layout. Manage the frame of your child view controller's view manually, and have delegate callbacks back to your parent view controller where necessary. In those delegate callbacks, your parent view controller can react to size changes of the child view controller's view.